# Can't upload to Amazon S3 with signed request via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, heroku, amazon-s3

I did everything as [Heroku recommended](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node), but I keep getting `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error. With message:

```
The request signature we calculated does not
match the signature you provided. Check your key
and signing method.
```

But I did'n mean to sign anything. I just want a link that I can direct download a file to.

Here are my aws config at Node JS server. I use them to generate a signed request. They provide me with a long link.

```
var s3_params = {
  Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
  Key: filename,
  Expires: 400,
  ContentType: fileType,
  ACL: 'public-read'
}
```

Am I right thinking that I don't need to have AWS secret key to upload a file with signed request?

Comment: When you do you get this error? When the user tries to upload or when you try to pre-sign the URL on the server?

Comment: When I try to upload. It pre-signs successfully. I can email a pre-signed url to anyone, who would be so kind to investigate.

Comment: Send it over to harsha ( a ) harshavardhana.net must be something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can take a look at *`mc`* tool that i wrote for simplicity, you can download binaries for OS X, Linux and Windows from https://github.com/minio/mc

```
$ mc share download --expiry=400s <YOUR-S3-URL>
```

*`mc`* also implements '--json' output so you can build a server side nodejs service easily. Without --expiry URL is shared with expiry for default 7days.

```
$ mc share download --json s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/distrikt_2014-01-31T07_31_11-08_00.mp3 | jq . 

{
  "status": "success",
  "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/distrikt_2014-01-31T07_31_11-08_00.mp3",
  "share": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/distrikt_2014-01-31T07_31_11-08_00.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI6SNMUFOVIEFOZJA%2F20151125%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20151125T002135Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=082e01d815e6aee8bc567d1d86d79d635b5313337dfba46524f35cfc6858e857",
  "timeLeft": 604800000000000
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in wrong credentials. I just forgot, that I deleted my secret key from AWS. I have recreated it and now everything works just fine.